# Calculus 2 Root Test Question help

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Hey can you guys help me with this root test question:
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(n^\sqrt n)}{2^n}$$

Comment: I can guess from your question that you want to find the convergence of the series
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n^{\sqrt n}}{2^n}$$
using the root test, but others might not be able to tell this, so please be more specific. You should also tell everyone *why you can't* solve the problem and where you are stuck. Please read the following guide about how to format as well: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Yes, we can help you, but we might not want to if you don't show your work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**HINT**

Note that

$$\sqrt[n]{\frac{n^{\sqrt n}}{2^n}}=\frac12 n^{\frac1{\sqrt n}}$$

and

$$n^{\frac1{\sqrt n}}=\left(\sqrt n^{\frac1{\sqrt n}}\right)^2$$

Comment: So after simplifying you would get limit (n->infty) $\frac{(\sqrt n^{1/\sqrt n})^2}{2}$ = $1/2$ because anything to the power of 1 would = 1. So it would converge because it is less than 1?

Comment: Yes exactly, you can conclude so.